# Background-color não acompanha conteúdo

Tags: css, css3

Bom, tenho o código abaixo e tenho uma dúvida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```css
.um {
  background-color:#000;
  width:600px;
  height:280px;
  margin:0 auto; /*centralizando horizontalmente esta div*/
}

.dois {  
  background-color:#CCC;
  width:300px;
  height:240px; 
  margin:0 auto; /*centralizando horizontalmente esta div*/
  line-height:240px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="um">

  <div class="dois">

    <div style="border:red 1px solid;">Teste 1!</div>
    <div style="border:red 1px solid;">Teste 2!</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

As `div's` filhas da `div.dois` estão tendo uma altura igual ao `line-height` da `div.dois` e não consigo centralizar verticalmente a `div.dois` no centro da `div.um`.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer que aconteça! Poderia explicar melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu `"background"` da `div` pai não acompanha as `div's` filhas pelo fato de você ter uma altura fixa nela, no caso o `height:240px;` tire ela e acompanha-rá.

E para alinha horizontalmente os elementos filhos basta colocar nelas um `margin: 0 auto;`!

```css
#pai {
  background-color:#000;
  width:600px;
  line-height:280px;
  text-align:center;      
}

.filho {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#CCC;
  width:300px;
  height:240px;   
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">

  <div class="filho">

    teste 2!

  </div>

  <div class="filho">

    teste 3!

  </div>

</div>
```

Agora se realmente tenha que `fixar` uma altura no elemento pai, não tem como o `background` acompanhar os filhos.

Comment: No último exemplo, como conseguir fazer com que os dois filhos fiquem um ao lado do outro usando float: left e float:right e o fundo do pai acompanhar?

Comment: @CarlosRocha É isto que está querendo fazer? Olha [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/iigormello/rght8n6z/2/)

Comment: Sim. Agora um conselho: Consegui arrumar de uma outra forma. Adicionei overflow: auto à (no meu caso) div 'um'. E o background acompanhou bacana. Qual jeito é mais correto? O que aqui demonstrou ou usando overflow? Lembrando que no meu caso tenho uma div ainda acima da div um que a engloba.(e só tem ela dentro)

Comment: @CarlosRocha Com o `overflow: auto;` o conteúdo interno da `div` **um** vai ficar no seu devido lugar, porém se ultrapassar as dimensões vai criar uma barra de rolagem para visualizar o resto do conteúdo. Não afirmaria um forma correta, depende de qual sua finalidade!

Comment: Entendi. Fiz esse teste e de fato deu a barra de rolagem. Mas você determinou na div.um   line-height:200px; Mas não dá ara determinar seu height pois o conteúdo dos filhos é dinãmico, ou seja, retorno de consulta ao banco podendo ter qualquer altura, Dessa forma, qual a saída?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Pode adicionar um outro elemento dentro da `div.um` por exemplo uma tag `p` e usar um `vertical-align` assim não importa o tamanho do texto que vai ser inserido ali. Dá uma olha no meu [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iigormello/rght8n6z/3/) que atualizei, se é assim que está querendo?

Comment: Então, minha necessidade é essa aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/rght8n6z/4/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38590/discussion-between-igor-mello-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: consegui: faltou depois do loop adicionar um <div style='clear:both;'></div>

Comment: @CarlosRocha OK!

Comment: obrigado. preciso estudar mais css

Comment: @CarlosRocha de nada, estamos aqui para isto!

Comment: @CarlosRocha e Igor Não é uma critica negativa, é apenas algo que discordo, na verdade o que você respondeu já continha na minha resposta, sobre a altura estar fixa, o AP só escolheu a sua resposta porque na verdade o código que ele tinha um problema era totalmente diferente do que ele postou na pergunta (ele estava usando `float`), ele escolheu mais a sua resposta pelo assistencialismo do que pelo que foi perguntando, se ele editar agora a pergunta irá invalidar tudo. Ou seja foi quase uma resposta duplicada (no entanto é permitido). Contudo eu realmente discordo de como se seguiu.

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento Aceito sua crítica, se é pelo fato de a solução (resposta correta sair da sua para vir para mim) sinta-se a vontade @CarlosRocha de reverter novamente, não estou aqui para "disputar votos" e sim para ajudar, disseminar e aprender cada vez mais conhecimento!

Answer (score 2):

Vou explicar os primeiros problemas, primeiro `vertical-align` é usado para elemento irmãos e que sejam `inline` ou `inline-*` (tipo texto), div por padrão são `block` o que é diferente do "tipo texto".

Ou seja você aplicou vertical-align esperando afetar objetos block e que são pai e filho e não irmãos, uma maneira de usar o vertical-align seria esta (isto não é solução é apenas pra explicar o vertical-align):

```css
.irmao-1 {
    background: #fc0;
    height: 160px;
}

.irmao-2 {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 240px;
}

.irmao-1, .irmao-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="irmao-1">
  Irmão 1
</div>
<div class="irmao-2">
  Irmão 2
</div>
```

Outra coisa que parece que talvez esteja confundindo é o termo background, o background só afeta o elemento em si, cada elemento vai ter o seu proprio background e a propriedade background nunca vai vazar o elemento.

Uma coisa, você não precisa "fixar" a altura de todos elementos, você poderia usar padding por exemplo:

```css
.pai {
   background-color: #000;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.filho {
   background-color: #ccc;
   width:300px;
   height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="filho">
       oi
    </div>
</div>
```

A soma do `height: 240px` com o `padding-top: 20px` e `padding-bottom: 20px` vai fazer o elemento pai ter `280px`

Um exemplo com duas divs:

```css
.pai {
   background-color: #000;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.filho-1 {
   margin: 0 auto; /*centraliza horizontal*/
   background-color: #ccc;
   width:300px;
   height: 240px;
}

.filho-2 {
   margin: 0 auto; /*centraliza horizontal*/
   background-color: #fc0;
   width:300px;
   height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="filho-1">
       oi
    </div>
    <div class="filho-2">
       oi
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Talvez eu não tenha sido bem objetivo na pergunta. Tenho as div's pai e filho. A div pai tem 280px de altura e a div filho tem 240px de altura. A div filho tem um background-color e o objetivo é que a div filho tenha seu conteúdo centralizado verticalmente e horizontalmente. Mas que a div filho (toda, incluindo seu background) fique alinhada em relação ao pai horizontalmente e verticalmente. Vou reler sua resposta com mais atenção mas se puder adicionar à resposta um exemplo desse tipo ficaria agradecido

Comment: @CarlosRocha a minha resposta dá uma breve solução sobre isso usando o padding, já que a altura é fixa, veja que o padding-top e padding-bottom são de 20px no elemento pai, se o filho tem 240px então o pai vai totalizar 280px, teste por favor.

Comment: @CarlosRocha por favor leia a parte que escrevei isto na resposta: *Uma coisa, você não precisa "fixar" a altura de todos elementos, você poderia usar padding por exemplo* e veja o exemplo, eu editei pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta baseada no que aprendi no que escreveu. Vê agora o que realmente está errado! Vou reler o detalhe das alturas

Comment: @CarlosRocha o segundo exemplo (aonde esta escrito *Uma coisa, você não precisa "fixar"*) resolve perfeitamente o problema de colocar duas divs no elemento pai. Se fixar a altura é que terá problemas. Teste o código, espero que funcione se não me avise =)

Comment: 1+ ótima explicação e organização parabéns pela resposta

Comment: @VictorGomes obrigado!

Comment: Sim, agora sim. O problema era mai com postion do que propriamente dito com valign. Obrigado